# Is there an option to update information on wordpress events plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, comments, updatepanel

I have a problem on on wordpress website: achordapp.co.il/alon 
I need to let users add comments on the events that in the calnedar. i'm publishing events and they need to approve it.

I already try to set there the wordpress comments section which wasn't working.
I thought maybe i could add a form (even on popup) that will update the wordpress relevant information.

front:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK33Q.jpg

backend:
as text- [approve/not] [text]

Thanks!

Comment: While I understand you may be desperate for help, I don't think it's a good idea to post login credentials on a public website like this...

Answer (score 0):

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support

If you add 'comments' support programmatically, then users will be able to add comments just like they can on normal posts.

Comment: Is this the code i should use?

<?php
/**
 * Enables the Excerpt meta box in Page edit screen.
 */
function wpcodex_add_excerpt_support_for_pages() {
 add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpcodex_add_excerpt_support_for_pages' );
?>